# A different and engrossing function

Tags: functions

> $f(x)=x!(x^2+x+1)$ is given. Find the sum
> $$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\dots+f(10)$$

I thought to multiply the equality by $x-1$, but I think it did not work. Do you have any idea about this question? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried finding $f(1), f(1) + f(2), f(1) + f(2) + f(3) $ to see if there is a pattern?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $x^2 + x + 1 = ( x+2)(x+1) - 2 (x+1) + 1$.

Hence, $x! (x^2+x+1) = ??$

Comment: @user535432 +1 to Calvin Lin for elegance.  However, I fail to see why this problem can not be solved by dispensing all elegance and algebra, and just using a calculator, pencil and paper.  Going up to $10$ is not that onerous.